# How to get a Windows 7 Home Premium copy?

Tags: windows-7, disk-operating-system

Few days back my hard drive stop working and I don't have any recovery of my operating system.
And when I bought this laptop they didn't provide any OS disc with it.

I want to know is there any way to get a Windows 7 Home Premium copy?

Comment: contact your laptop manufacturer. otherwise if you do find a disk elsewhere, make sure it is an OEM edition, so you can install it with the license key that came with your laptop. Retail media will NOT activate with that key (it will install though).

Comment: Frank is correct, find someone who has an OEM install.  Dell was pretty good about providing a pure OEM disc.  Keep in mind that you will have to locate and install all your drivers after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the major OEMs (Dell, HP, etc.) allow you to buy a recovery disc if you did not order one with your computer or burn your own.  Just contact the manufacturer of your computer and they will help you place the order.  Usually it's around $15.

Answer (score 0):

You can download ISO Files from these links

Windows 7 Home Premium x86 with SP1 (bootable)

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24208.iso

Windows  7  Home Premium x64 with SP1 (bootable)

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24209.iso

Use your Genuine Windows 7 HP Key to activate window.

PS - Digital River hosts the content for Microsoft's online stores, so yes it's safe to use.

Source - Microsoft Technet Community Moderator.

Comment: The digital river links no longer work.